# What does the following error mean? TypeError: arithmetic_arranger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'results'

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm working on an arithmetic arranger problem.

The program arranges and returns the problem as shown below in the console output. It is a function that accepts two parameters: a list where each item is an addition or subtraction problem, and an optional second argument that, when true, displays each answer beneath the dashes under each problem.

I've searched the error online, but I can't seem to find a helpful solution. To me, it looks like the program is failing 5 out of the 6 tests in the test_module file. However, the error message is the same for all 5 test failures:

**TypeError: arithmetic_arranger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'results'**

Here's the console output when I run the program:

```
 python main.py
   32      3801      50      123        12
+ 698    -    2    + 50    -  49    + 3600
-----    ------    ----    -----    ------
  730      3799     100       74      3612
EEE.EE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_arrangement (test_module.UnitTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/boilerplate-arithmetic-formatter-4/test_module.py", line 8, in test_arrangement
    actual = arithmetic_arranger(["3 + 855", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
TypeError: arithmetic_arranger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'results'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_incorrect_operator (test_module.UnitTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/boilerplate-arithmetic-formatter-4/test_module.py", line 22, in test_incorrect_operator
    actual = arithmetic_arranger(["3 / 855", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
TypeError: arithmetic_arranger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'results'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_only_digits (test_module.UnitTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/boilerplate-arithmetic-formatter-4/test_module.py", line 32, in test_only_digits
    actual = arithmetic_arranger(["98 + 3g5", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
TypeError: arithmetic_arranger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'results'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_too_many_digits (test_module.UnitTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/boilerplate-arithmetic-formatter-4/test_module.py", line 27, in test_too_many_digits
    actual = arithmetic_arranger(["24 + 85215", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
TypeError: arithmetic_arranger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'results'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_too_many_problems (test_module.UnitTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/boilerplate-arithmetic-formatter-4/test_module.py", line 17, in test_too_many_problems
    actual = arithmetic_arranger(["44 + 815", "909 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49", "888 + 40", "653 + 87"])
TypeError: arithmetic_arranger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'results'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.061s

FAILED (errors=5)
```

Here's the code from my arithmetic_arranger file:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, results):
  if len(problems) > 5:
    return 'Error: Too many problems.'
  
  top = []
  bottom = []
  dashes = []
  spaces = '    '
  answers = []

# ["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "50 + 50", "123 - 49", "12 + 3600"]

  for problem in problems:
    first = '  ' + problem.split()[0]
    second = problem.split(' ', 1)[1]
    length_first = len(first)
    length_second = len(second)
    difference_first = length_first - length_second
    difference_second = length_second - length_first

    width_first = len(problem.split()[0])
    width_second = len(problem.split()[2])

    if width_first > 4 or width_second > 4:
      return "Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits."
      
    if second[0] != '+' and second[0] != '-':
      return "Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'."
    
    if first.lstrip().isdigit() != True or second[2:].isdigit() != True:
      return 'Error: Numbers must only contain digits.'
    
    if difference_first > 0:
      second = second[0] + ' ' * (difference_first + 1) + second[2:]
    elif difference_second > 0:
      first = ' ' * difference_second + first

    # Optional condition to display answers under problems:
    if results:
      if second[0] == '+':
        answer = int(first) + int(second[2:])
      else:
        answer = int(first) - int(second[2:])

      answer_to_string = str(answer)
      length_result = len(answer_to_string)
      answer_to_string = '  ' + answer_to_string
      length_maximum = max([len(first.lstrip()), len(second[1:].lstrip())])

      if length_maximum > length_result:
        answer_to_string = ' ' * (length_maximum - length_result) + answer_to_string
      elif length_maximum < length_result:
        answer_to_string = answer_to_string[1:]

      answers.append(answer_to_string)

  # Append variables to lists
    top.append(first)
    bottom.append(second)
    dashes.append('-' * len(second))

  # Set spacing
    spaced_top = spaces.join(top)
    spaced_bottom = spaces.join(bottom)
    spaced_dashes = spaces.join(dashes)
    spaced_answers = spaces.join(answers)
  
  return spaced_top + '\n' + spaced_bottom + '\n' + spaced_dashes + '\n' + spaced_answers
```

Here's the code from my main.py file:

```
# This entrypoint file to be used in development. Start by reading README.md
from arithmetic_arranger import arithmetic_arranger
from unittest import main


print(arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "50 + 50", "123 - 49", "12 + 3600"], True))


# Run unit tests automatically
main(module='test_module', exit=False)
```

Here's the code from my test_module.py file:

```
import unittest
from arithmetic_arranger import arithmetic_arranger


# the test case
class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_arrangement(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["3 + 855", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
        expected = "    3      3801      45      123\n+ 855    -    2    + 43    +  49\n-----    ------    ----    -----"
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected different output when calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with ["3 + 855", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]')

        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["11 + 4", "3801 - 2999", "1 + 2", "123 + 49", "1 - 9380"])
        expected = "  11      3801      1      123         1\n+  4    - 2999    + 2    +  49    - 9380\n----    ------    ---    -----    ------"
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected different output when calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with ["11 + 4", "3801 - 2999", "1 + 2", "123 + 49", "1 - 9380"]')

    def test_too_many_problems(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["44 + 815", "909 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49", "888 + 40", "653 + 87"])
        expected = "Error: Too many problems."
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with more than five problems to return "Error: Too many problems."')

    def test_incorrect_operator(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["3 / 855", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
        expected = "Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'."
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, '''Expected calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with a problem that uses the "/" operator to return "Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'."''')
        
    def test_too_many_digits(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["24 + 85215", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
        expected = "Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits."
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with a problem that has a number over 4 digits long to return "Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits."')

    def test_only_digits(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["98 + 3g5", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
        expected = "Error: Numbers must only contain digits."
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with a problem that contains a letter character in the number to return "Error: Numbers must only contain digits."')

    def test_solutions(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["32 - 698", "1 - 3801", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"], True)
        expected = "   32         1      45      123\n- 698    - 3801    + 43    +  49\n-----    ------    ----    -----\n -666     -3800      88      172"
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected solutions to be correctly displayed in output when calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with arithmetic problems and a second argument of `True`.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In your unit tests, you've only given one parameter

Comment: Are you referring to this parameter: self ? If so, how would I correct this?

Comment: Nope. `actual = arithmetic_arranger([...])`. You're missing your True/False parameter in multiple places, as the error says

Comment: I added True to each unit test and now it's down to only one failure, thank you!